# I want to convert this switch part of code in single line using ternary operators

Tags: switch-statement, conditional-statements, shortcode, conditional-operator, short

```
for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    switch(num[i]/10){
        case 10:
        case 9:
            aCount++;
            break;
        case 8:
            bCount++;
            break;
        case 7:
            cCount++;
            break;
        case 6:
            dCount++;
            break;
        default: fCount++;
    }
```

I want to short this code using multiple ternary operators in single line instead of switch statement. is it possible?

Comment: is really ugly, but is possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'll hate yourself the first time you need to make a change in it, and others you work with will ask to work with anyone besides you because it will be virtually impossible for someone who didn't write it to understand it, but if you're willing to live with those consequences you can do what you're asking. Personally, if you worked on my team and I was involved in your code review, I'd reject the multiple ternary version as unmaintainable and make you change it back.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, no. First up, you haven't specified the *language,* it *may* be possible in C++ by using references, or in C by using pointers. But, even if it *is* possible, you'll most likely end up with truly *ugly* code.

If you're just looking to improve readability (the usual reason for shorter code, in my opinion), that can be done *without* changing the structure of the code, something like (assuming those are marks `0..100` and grades `a..f`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    // Map <60 to f, 6x to d, 7x to c, 8x to b, 90+ to a.

    switch (num[i] / 10) {
        case 10: case 9: aCount++; break;
        case 8:          bCount++; break;
        case 7:          cCount++; break;
        case 6:          dCount++; break;
        default:         fCount++;
    }
}
```